# Independent random number generators

Tags: scala, random

I need to create independent random number generators in scala from a given one, something similar to haskell's split function. Can I use the current number generator to produce ints or longs, and use these as seed to create new generators?

```
val rng: Random 
val seed1 = rng.nextLong()
val seed2 = rng.nextLong()

val rng1 = new Random(seed1)
val rng2 = new Random(seed2)
```

Is this a good way to do it? Or does it screw the sequence of randomness (for example, by relying on Ints or Longs which may carry less information than the actual state of a random number generator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the specific algorithm used for generating pseudo-random numbers. If the documentation doesn't promise it gives independent streams (and Java's doesn't), assume it won't work well. Terms like "multiple streams", "parallel streams", or "splittable" can also be used.

I believe MRG32k3a is the most popular generator with multiple stream support. You can easily find Java implementations online, but the ones I did are GPL-licensed, so I refrained from including them. [PCG](http://www.pcg-random.org/) also supports multiple streams and there is a [Scala implementation](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/spire/random/rng/PcgXshRr64_32.scala) in Spire. (And a Java implementation at https://github.com/alexeyr/pcg-java).

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what your usecase is.

If you just want to make sure the rngs numbers advance independently (e.g., each thread or actor gets an rng and you want to stay deterministic), your approach is fine.